# How to add dynamic route in Sammy.js

Tags: history.js, sammy.js

Can I add/define dynamic route on some click event using sammy.js or any other alternative plugin for this

```
var app = $.sammy('#sidebar', function () {
  this.get("#/", function(){});
});

$(function(){
app.run("#/");

$("#btn").click(function(){
   app.addRoute ???????????
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First select the Sammy app

```
var app = Sammy('#main');
```

Since Sammy evaluates the routes in order, we need to ensure that the new route gets added before any catch all routes.

First create the route:

```
app.get('/Test/', function() { alert('new route') });
```

Then move it from bottom of the array to the top:

```
app.routes.get.unshift(app.routes.get.pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already gotten this figured out by now, but the question should have an answer. You can add routes to the Sammy application at any point, just like when you use 'this' inside your original call.

```
var app = $.sammy('#sidebar', function () {
    this.get("#/", function(){});
});

$(function(){
    app.run("#/");

    $("#btn").click(function(){
        // Add a new route to Sammy
        app.get('#/newroute/:id', function(context) { console.log(context) });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var app = $.sammy('#sidebar', function() {
    this.get("#/", function(){});
});

$(function() {
    app.run("#/");

    $("#btn").click(function() {
        //the callback can be a string to be parsed by the eval function, but is not recommended
        var callback = function() {
            //what you want to do the new route
        };

        //use the same get function from Sammy to add the new Route
        this.get('your new route', callback);
    });
});
```